# How to set all 0s into an array declared through structure (C)?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

while I was practicing with C programming I found a problem about arrays with structs.
In particular, I'm going to make a program to operate with different polynomials; so I declared a struct "Pol" which contains the variable "order" and the array "coefficients".
Then I'm going to make soe operations with polynomials (for example the sum between two of them).
The problem is about how to declare the array "coefficients" in the structure, because when I want to sum two polynomials I want to set all the elements of the array to 0 (to solve the problem about the sum of two polynomials with differents orders).
I know how to set 0s into an array declared in main function (setting a single value to 0, and then all the others are automatically set to 0).
But how can I do the same with the structure?

Thank you in advance to all people who are going to help me.

I public the code (not finished) below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define N_MAX 100

typedef struct
{
  float coefficients[N_MAX];
  int order;
} Pol;

void println(int n);
void readPol(Pol* pol);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  Pol p1, p2, pS;

  readPol(&p1);
  return 0;
}

void readPol(Pol* pol)
{
  printf("Polynomial order: ");
  scanf("%d", &pol->order);
  println(1);

  for(int i = pol->order; i >= 0; i--)
    {
      printf("Coefficient of x^[%d]: ", i);
      scanf("%f", &pol->coefficients[i]);
    }
}

void println(int n)
{
  for(; n > 0; n--)
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: In ReadPol you need a test that order > 0 and order < N_MAX.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for initializing a struct is similar to how an array is initialized.  You specify the initializers in order, putting braces around any nested initializers:

```
Pol p1 = { { 0 }, 0 };
```

Answer (score 2):

> ... want to set all the elements of the array to 0

To initialize (assign at declaration time), various choices.

```
Pol pol1 = { .order = 0, .coefficients = { 0 } };    // Declare members in desired order
Pol pol2 = { .coefficients = { 0 }, .order = 0 };
Pol pol3 = { .order = 0, .coefficients = { 0.0f } }; // A float constant for clarity
Pol pol4 = { { 0.0f }, 0 };                          // Order matches declaration 
Pol pol5 = { 0 };                                    // All set to 0
```

Note that with partial explicit initializers, remaining members/array elements get a 0 value.  (0 for integer types, 0.0 for FP, types, some *null pointer* for pointer types.)

In C, there is no partial initialization, all or nothing.

---

To *assign*, a direct solution is to use a loop.

```
pol->order = 0;
for(i = 0; i < N_MAX; i++) {
  pol->coefficients[i] = 0.0f;
}
```

---

But why? All code needs is

```
pol->order = 0;
pol->coefficients[0] = 0.0f;
```

The point of having a `.order` member is to scale the work to the used size of the array as well done in `readPol(Pol* pol)` and `println(int n)`. Not spend time assigning unused array members.

Answer (score -1):

You can initialize each byte of variable with memset.

```
memset(&p1, 0, sizeof(Pol))
```

Comment: Just wondering, why is this downvoted? Is this bad practice to do?